# Auto install a font used on my website

Tags: css, web, fonts

I am using a custom font on my site and in search of a way that this font will be installed automatically on the user's system who is opening the site.

Is there any script or any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is Yes!

New in CSS3 is @font-face, which tells a browser to download a font and use it to render some text. [This is an an example I made with jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eEHpQ/). The caveat with @font-face is that each browser requires a different file type to work. On websites like [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) you can use fonts that will work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [font squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) has an easy-to-use generator that will transform your font into various formats appropriate for different browsers.

The font is not actually installed on the user's machine, it's linked remotely, like an image or script. There's no way to automatically install things on people's machines for obvious security reasons.